# pyinstaller failed to process no matter how I try

Tags: python, pyinstaller

c:\program files\python35\scripts> pyinstaller.exe --onefile "path\whatever\main.py"

c:\program files\python35\scripts> pyinstaller --onefile "path\whatever\main.py"

fails to process

also tried running pyinstaller from the path where main.py is located and still nothing.

working with  python 3.5.2, 64bit

Thank you

Comment: do `pyinstaller --version` also raise the same error?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the following steps to create standalone `exe` file from a python file.

**System Information:**

- Operation system: Windows 8
- Python: 3.6.2
- Package: `pyinstaller` - 3.3.1

**Why do we need `virtualenv`?**

`virtualenv` is not a mandatory requirement of creating `exe` file. But it is an useful tool to create isolated Python environments for different projects. It keeps the global packages and project specific packages separate. In our case we are keeping `pyinstaller` isolate from global installation thus using it in virtual environment.

**Install Virtualenv package globally:**

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

**Create and activate virtual environment:**

```
virtualenv -p python3 venv
source venv/bin/activate (Linux)
venv\Scripts\activate (Windows)
```

---

If you find it too complex, you can do the following steps even without performing the above steps. It will install `pyinstaller` globally in the machine.

---

**Install Pyinstaller inside the `venv`:**

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

**Create `exe` file**:

```
pyinstaller main.py -F
```

Here my python file is called `main.py`.

The converted exe can be found in `dist` folder.

Comment: thank you, can you explain more about the virtual env?

Comment: Updated the answer. If you find it useful do upvote and accept it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: thank you for your help but i'm still far behind... everything that I type in the command prompt now is resdponded by "XXX is not recognized as an internal or external command..." by the way I'm with win 7, does it matter?

Comment: I do not think so. Share the command you are trying to execute and the response too.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Python35\Scripts> pyinstaller main.py

main.py is my py code
and '...scripts' is the path where pyinstaller is installed, and where I put the py code too

I just saw a youtube running exactly like that but for me it does not work.
all the venv settings I dd through pycharm, but I have no idea how to access them from outside pycharm and also how it should help my create an exe file